# SQL script to group and update based on a specific number of consecutive repeats of same text

Tags: sql-server

I found this script to select consecutive items and update another field for each when for example n=4.  I can't find how to do it in SQL and this script works but is written in postgre SQL which I don't use.

```
update newLocations m
set description=
             (select MAX(n.id2_location) 
              from locations n
              where m.id_location=n.id_location )
where exists
(select *
from locations n2
where m.id_location=n2.id_location);

SELECT *
FROM NEWLOCATIONS;
```

The fiddle is here http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/dbb5a/89

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `UPDATE FROM` syntax:

```
UPDATE nl
    SET nl.description = (
        SELECT MAX(l.id2_location)
        FROM locations l 
        WHERE l.id_location = nl.id_location
    )
FROM newlocations nl
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM locations l
    WHERE l.id_location = nl.id_location
);
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response.  The final task is to only select repeats when n=4, for example.  I tried adding   "and count(nl.id_location) >4" to the WHERE conditions but it fails!  Any ideas why?